# Solr with Zookeeper and own schema

Tags: solr, schema, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I'm a newbie to SOLR and there's a problem I can't solve so far: When I'm starting SOLR cloud with Zookeeper I like to create a collection with a personal schema. However, SOLR only loads the default 'example-data-driven-schema'.

Any suggestion what I should do in order to put my defined schema to it?

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a new collection with your own schema, you need to use [zkCli.sh](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperStarted.html) and [SolrCloud Collection API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API).

In particular,  you could:

a) upload in Zookeeper (using Solr  zkCli) the configuration directory for your new collection,  for instance in

```
<my_new_config>
```

Examples of Solr ZkCli commands to upload your changes in ZooKeeper can be found [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Command+Line+Utilities). 
In particular, if you want to upload your configuration directory on Zk,  you can:

STEP 1) run the command:

```
./server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost 127.0.0.1:9983 \   -cmd upconfig -confname my_new_config -confdir server/solr/configsets/basic_configs/conf
```

STEP 2) Restart your Solr nodes so they can pick up the configuration changes.

Please remember that if you wish to replace an existing file in Zk you will need to use zkCli.sh *clear* to delete the existing one from ZooKeeper and then the *putfile* command to add the new one.

b) call the following API from your browser:

```
/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=<my_collection_name>&collection.configName=<my_new_config>
```

Comment: Thanks!!
But I found out how to upload a configset at the creation of a new collection. I'm doing it via the console from my Linux Ubuntu 14 VM. But the issue I got is this:
Once the Configset is uploaded, and i Change something in the configset, how can i reload it inside of the ZooKeeper? I've delete all the log.-Dates in the .../zoo_data/Version-2/ Directory and tried to upload all my configsets manually, but i got SOLR-Error that no collection found its config.
What do I have to do step by step, when I want to have my changes into the ZooKeeper, too?
Using solr-6.0.1 in Cloud-mode.

Comment: Thx! Tried what you said. Created new collection, named "MySchemas" and gave it "schema_test_configset", changed display name in managed-schema of configset and tried change config inside ZooKeeper with various tries:
$ server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost localhost:9983 -cmd clear /.../solr-6.0.1/server/solr/configsets/schema_test_configset
$ server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost localhost:9983 -cmd upconfig -confname schema_test_configs -confdir /.../solr-6.0.1/server/solr/configsets/schema_test_configset/conf
..but changes didn't work but also got no errors.What's wrong?

Comment: Hi,  you need to restart all the Solr nodes so they will pick up the changes that you made on ZooKeeper.

Comment: I know that i need to restart SOLR after I applied changes to the ZooKeeper but the problem is: how do i do changes on the ZooKeeper? Is my syntax wrong?